# How One can make a variable right to access from ONLY two functions that a file consists of total five functions

Tags: c

How One can access a variable from ONLY two functions that a file consists of total five functions.(No global or static declaration)

Comment: Not possible. If you want to make the variable invisible to three functions move them to another file and don't declare the variable in it.

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't in C; the file is the compilation unit that defines the boundaries for `static` variables of that sort, since anyone who can edit or view that file could work with all of the functions in it. If you really need to separate visibility, you have to split the functions into multiple files.

Comment: in one file you put the functions that need access to the variable and you declare and define the variable, in the other file you put the other functions, and you include each one in the other